# Assigning increasing values in blocks

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with the following characteristics:
RecordId- unique identifier
Date, weight and a control(1 if weight >10000 0 otherwise).

```
RecordID    Date    Weight  Control
1           16/07/2014  12200   1
2           16/07/2014  0       0
3           16/07/2014  5720    0
4           16/07/2014  11060   1
5           16/07/2014  15940   1
6           16/07/2014  16200   1
7           16/07/2014  16080   1
8           16/07/2014  16080   1
9           16/07/2014  16080   1
10          18/07/2014  16080   1
11          18/07/2014  3720    0
12          18/07/2014  4500    0
13          18/07/2014  23800   1
14          18/07/2014  40700   1
15          18/07/2014  40700   1
```

And I would like to add a new column (Group) which assign to each group of 0 and 1 the same increasing number as follows:

```
RecordID    Date    Weight  Control Group
1            16/07/2014 12200   1   1
2            16/07/2014 0       0   2
3            16/07/2014 5720    0   2
4            16/07/2014 11060   1   3
5            16/07/2014 15940   1   3
6            16/07/2014 16200   1   3
7            16/07/2014 16080   1   3
8            16/07/2014 16080   1   3
9            16/07/2014 16080   1   3
10           18/07/2014 16080   1   3
11           18/07/2014 3720    0   4
12           18/07/2014 4500    0   4
13           18/07/2014 23800   1   5
14           18/07/2014 40700   1   5
15           18/07/2014 40700   1   5
```

Please help me to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Which database is this for? MS SQL, MySQL, Oracle? Please add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Microsoft Transact SQL.

Here's a solution using a CASE WHEN statement to identify the change in the Control column.

I've named the table with the original data (RecordID, Date, Weight and Control) as 'Flori' in the below T-SQL.

```sql
SELECT      f.RecordID, f.Date, f.Weight, f.Control, 
            SUM(x.Change) OVER (ORDER BY f.RecordId) + 1 as [Group]
FROM 
            (SELECT RecordID, 
                (SELECT 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN Control != 
                             (SELECT Control FROM Flori WHERE RecordId = f.RecordID - 1)  
                            THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                    END
                ) as Change
            FROM Flori as f) as x
INNER JOIN  Flori f on x.RecordID = f.RecordID
GROUP BY    f.RecordID, f.Date, f.Weight, f.Control, x.Change
```